# How to enable 'Performance Overlay' in Flutter Dev Tool

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, ide

I have 2 flutter projects but one of them is disable Performance Overlay. How can I enable it?

Both projects run in VS Code, Profile Mode, real device.

**WORK**

[image]

**NOT WORK**

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Make sure that you’re running in **`profile mode`**, and that you’re not using an emulator.

For Android Studio : use the Run > **`Flutter Run main.dart in Profile Mode`** menu item.

In VS Code, open your launch.json file, and set the flutterMode property to profile (when done profiling, change it back to release or debug)

```
"configurations": [
      {
        "name": "Flutter",
        "request": "launch",
        "type": "dart",
        "flutterMode": "profile"
      }
    ]
```

For more details : [Flutter performance profiling](https://flutter.dev/docs/perf/rendering/ui-performance)

For performance overlay graph : Add this inside the widget build method at top level

```
showPerformanceOverlay: true
```

Comment: `showPerformanceOverlay` should be added to [Material App](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialApp/showPerformanceOverlay.html)